# Is there anyway to buy NFT on solana devnet?

Tags: nft, devnet

I'm now developing NFT-backed loan site and now on solana devnet.
I want to buy NFT to test on solana devnet.
Is there any marketplace on solana devnet like magiceden?
if anyone know, please help me.
this is urgent.
thanks.

Comment: Unless you have some specific reason you need to buy it, it'd probably be easiest to just use Metaplex candy machine and mint an NFT to yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this dapp in your local. The site is no longer being maintained.

https://github.com/ilmoi/nft-armory